# .NET can´t connect to MySQL with ODBC 5.3?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net

I have a ASP.NET webform .NET 4.5 website that uses MySQL ODBC to communicate with the MySQL Database. This is working just fine with the 5.1.13 32bit driver but if I uninslla this and install 5.3.4 32bit driver I get the following exception when connecting :

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
>   Data source name not found and no default driver specified

The connectionstring Im using is this

```
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 `Driver};SERVER=127.0.0.1;PORT=3306;DATABASE=mydatabase;USER=myuser;PASSWORD=mypassword;OPTION=3`
```

All I changed is from `MySQL ODBC 5.1` to `MySQL ODBC 5.3`.

this is the code that fails(where I can see the correct(above) connectionstring.

```
dataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(inCommandObj);
                mainConnection.Open();
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with driver name "MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver"

updated connection string:

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};SERVER=127.0.0.1;PORT=3306;DATABASE=mydatabase;USER=myuser;PASSWORD=mypassword;OPTION=3
```